# Rails form_for action has a corrupted locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an account dashboard that lists the offices and for each office the jobs available.

Hierarchy:

- Companies (1 user has 1 company, I access if from the user profile)
- Offices (each company can have multiple offices)
- Jobs (each office can have multiple jobs)

Models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :jobs, :through => :offices

class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
```

For each job I have an edit link

E.g. for job id 10 (job is a local variable from iteration on office jobs)

= link_to edit_job_path(I18n.locale, job)

-> localhost:3000/de/jobs/10/edit

When I click on the edit link, I go to the edit page. So far so good, but the form looks like that:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/10/jobs/10" class="edit_job" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_job_10" method="post">
```

Notice, that my locale (de in this example) disappeared and has the job id instead!

My routes.rb

```
scope "/:locale" do
    resources :companies
    resources :offices do
            resources :jobs
    end
    resources :jobs
end
```

There are two jobs mentioned, I probably can do without but it's an easy way for me to either mention directly the job url to view or add office variable in the create new job link and use :office_id (in my dashboard controller: link_to new_office_job_path(I18n.locale, office) then in my form for new jobs: = f.hidden_field :office_id)

But even if I remove the resources :jobs in the :offices. The locale is still replaced by the job id in the edit form.

Note that I can edit the job properly, but because the locale is changed, the localisation text are all wrong after my redirect.

Any idea how to fix that?

------ Additional data requested -----------

```
= form_for(@job) do |f|
    .field
        = f.label :name, t(:job_title)
        = f.text_field :name
    .field
        = f.label :url, t(:job_url)
        = f.text_field :url
    .field
        = f.hidden_field :office_id
    .field
        = f.label :pdf, t(:job_upload_pdf)
        = f.file_field :pdf
    .field
        = f.label :tag_list, t(:job_tags)
        = f.text_field :tag_list
    .actions
        = f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

------ Additional information -----------

BTW: this work around works, I get /de/jobs/10 but I'd like to understand why the locale gets corrupted if I use the default form_for.

```
  = form_for @job, :url => job_path(I18n.locale, @job) do |f|
```

Comment: your issue is most probably in the form itself. can you include the code for the edit form in your question?

Comment: The form is very similar to the 'new job' form, that keeps the locale untouched. link to new: localhost:3000/de/offices/5/jobs/new (using the other resource in route) -> form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/de/jobs" class="new_job" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_job" method="post"

Comment: Running `url_for(@job)` gives me an error which baffles me why you're not getting any. i was able to fix it by passing an `as` option to the scope in the routes and use the named_route generated.  something like `locale_job_path(params[:locale], @job)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the locale using a [Routing Filter](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter), I've tried it in my project, you don't have to worry about locale in routes, the filter will handle it for you.

```
# in config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  filter :locale
end
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Simon, I'm happy with my routes the way they are. The question is why is the local using the id of the job instead of the locale when other forms (like new job) are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `form_for` line builds the path, when building the path you also need to specify the locale. To do this cleanly (without specifying the url explicitly, which is also possible), write it as follows:

```
= form_for [I18n.locale, @job] do |f|
```

and that should render the correct path.
As specified in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) it will use the array to build the correct path (this works for namespaced and nested routes, so I am guessing it will also work for your locale).

An alternative is to specify the path explicitly, using the `:url` option.

HTH.

Comment: Well, that answer is what I already stated at the end. The question is why is the locale path corrupted in the first place and other form_for are fine (like for new).

Comment: Did you try the `form_for [I18n.locale, @job]` form? Are you sure `I18n.locale` is set? We use a `before_filter` in the application controller, that always sets the locale based on the `params[:locale]`, cookie or user settings (in that order).

Comment: I got that in application controller indeed. That is why I'm puzzled. before_filter :set_locale
  
 def set_locale
   I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
 end
And locale is correctly present in params too.